# What is the reason for firebase functions deploy crashing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When deploying via firebase deploy --only functions I recently get the following error messages:

In the console:

```
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (90.26 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function firestoreEmail(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function apiMain(us-central1)...
✔  functions[apiMain(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
⚠  functions[firestoreEmail(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try deploying again after a few minutes.

Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

In the log:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":13,"message":"Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try deploying again after a few minutes."},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"myemail@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/functions/firestoreEmail"}
```

Comment: Did you try deploying again in a few minutes as the message suggested?

Comment: Is your internet connectivity good?I mean the speed.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did, many times over the timespan of maybe one and a half hour.

Comment: @SushantSomani Internet speed is fine.

Comment: What's the output of 'firebase login' command?

Comment: @SushantSomani The output is ... already logged in. Logging out and in again, all looks good. No error message or the like.

Comment: For deployment errors like this, you should contact Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow is probably going to not be of any help. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/